# Scrapy Pipeline not insert data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I'm making a pipeline in scrapy to store scraped data in a mysql database. When the spider is run in terminal it works perfectly. Even the pipeline is opened. However the data is not being sent to the database. Any help appreciated! :)

here's the pipeline code:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

import datetime
import logging
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from en_movie.items import EnMovie



class DuplicatesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['image_urls'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['image_urls'])
            return item



class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = ', '.join(image_paths)
        return item



class EnMovieStorePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",      passwd="pass", db="passdb", charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()



    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM dmmactress_enmovielist WHERE Content_ID = %s and release_date = %s and running_time = %s and Actress = %s and Series = %s and Studio = %s and Director = %s and Label = %s and image_paths = %s and image_urls = %s""",
        (item['Content_ID'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['release_date'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['running_time'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Actress'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Series'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Studio'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Director'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Label'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['image_urls'][0].encode('utf-8')))
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()


        if result:
            print("data already exist")
        else:
            try:
                 cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dmmactress_enmovielist(Content_ID, release_date, running_time, Actress, Series, Studio, Director, Label, image_paths, image_urls) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
                (item['Content_ID'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['release_date'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['running_time'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Actress'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Series'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Studio'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Director'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['Label'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['image_urls'][0].encode('utf-8')))
                 self.conn.commit()
             except MySQLdb.Error as e:
                 print ("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
                 return item
```

EDIT:

```
  def parse_item(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="contents"]/div[10]/section/section[1]/section[1]'):
        item = EnMovie()
        Content_ID = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl/dt[contains (.,"Content ID:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['Content_ID'] = Content_ID[0].encode('utf-8')
        release_date = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[1]/dt[contains (.,"Release Date:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['release_date'] = release_date[0].encode('utf-8')
        running_time = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[1]/dt[contains (.,"Runtime:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['running_time'] = running_time[0].encode('utf-8')
        Series = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[2]/dt[contains (.,"Series:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['Series'] = Series[0].encode('utf-8')
        Studio = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[2]/dt[contains (.,"Studio:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/a/text())').extract()
        item['Studio'] = Studio[0].encode('utf-8')
        Director = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[2]/dt[contains (.,"Director:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['Director'] = Director[0].encode('utf-8')
        Label = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[2]/dl[2]/dt[contains (.,"Label:")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text())').extract()
        item['Label'] = Label[0].encode('utf-8')
        item['image_urls'] = sel.xpath('div[1]/img/@src').extract()

        actresses = sel.xpath("//*[@itemprop='actors']//*[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract()
        actress = [x.strip() for x in actresses]
        item['Actress'] = ", ".join(actress)
        yield item
```

Comment: Did you get any errors? Can you show how your `item` looks like?

Comment: Hello. Harrison. I didn't get any errors. so, I really don't know what's wrong with my pipeline. (I've modify my post for your reply) Thank you.

Comment: Most your `item` fields, except `image_urls`, are strings. Try remove `[0]`s after `item['Content_ID']`, `item['release_date']`, etc, except `item['image_urls']`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working a few weeks ago but switched to a different database.  At the time I based some code off of this:  https://gist.github.com/tzermias/6982723

Also remember to update your settings.py file as well if you use the above code...

Comment: Sorry, I should add that the linked code worked for mysql